# Applet lifecycle when out of focus

Tags: java, applet, japplet, javapos

Does a Java Applet always execute its code even when it losts focus? I've to put this applet in a web page.
I'm tryng to understand this cause i've to develop an applet that listen to some hardware components through JavaPos. I have a callback method defined inside the applet and i'm not sure if it works even when users click on other page component.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a Java Applet always execute its code even when it losts focus?

Yes, unless of course the applet code intentionally stops execution on loss of focus.

Comment: thanks
i've simulated input from hardware with a keylistener.. and this seems to be strictly related with the focus of the listening component